# How to exit Ctrl+Alt+F1 in Xubuntu

Tags: boot, nvidia, xubuntu

I am using xubuntu. My OpenGl Renderer was nonexistant, so I decided to download it. I found an article that would let me. I needed to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to finish. I pressed it, and my screen went black. I decided to exit, but i didn't know how. So, I did a hard reset. I had also recently reinstalled xorg.

Anyway, when I rebooted, I still had a black screen. I have tried everthing. I have tried `chvt 7`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, you name it. I know I'm in the right terminal, but all I have is a single black line with no text option. Help!

Comment: correction: All i get is a flashing yellow dash

Comment: Try Alt + <- (left arrow). Press these several times (together, or hold Alt first , then arrow). Also are there any messages ? Once you get the black screen, what do you see - just a login prompt or something saying about `ash` and `initramfs`  ?

Comment: Moreover, what did you do to your system that *ended* with having to press Ctrl+Alt+F1? Makes no sense to me

Answer (score 2):

It may take a few seconds before <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> puts something on the black screen, and even after that, it may take additional seconds before a  login prompt appears. When you see the login prompt enter your user name, and hit return. Then again, it may take awhile before another prompt on the black screen appears asking for your password. Sometimes it helps if you repeat the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Once your password is accepted eventually a terminal prompt will be seen on the black screen. At that point enter the command `sudo reboot`. This will shut down the machine in an orderly fashion and will reboot the system. Once rebooted you may want to try recovery mode or just boot normally.